# Apache mod_rewrite to remove .html extension not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I know this is going to be something STUPID, but I have been banging my head against a brick wall for the last few hours trying to figure it out. I simply cannot get a fresh Apache2.4 install to find the url mysite.com/signup (where signup.html) exists.

If I navigate to mysite.com/signup.html, everything works. But if I navigate to mysite.com/signup, I get a 404.

Here are the rewrites that I am using

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule (.*)  $1.html [L]
```

Here is the result of debugging the rewrite

```
[rewrite:trace3] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri '/signup'
[rewrite:trace4] RewriteCond: input='/signup' pattern='!-d' => matched
[rewrite:trace4] RewriteCond: input='/signup' pattern='!-f' => matched
[rewrite:trace4] RewriteCond: input='/signup.html' pattern='-f' => not-matched
[rewrite:trace1] pass through /signup
```

As you can see, the 4th log output *should* (I believe) be matching as the file signup.html does in fact exist by virtue of the fact that I can navigate directly to it.

Note that I am making changes directly in my conf file for my vhost as opposed to in htaccess.

What am I missing!!!
Thanks
Jab

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(htm|html)$

   RewriteRule /([0-9A-Za-z@.]+)$ /$1.html [QSA,R=307]
```

Comment: thanks for this. It partially works for me. If I dont use .html on the URL, it appends it and then it works. However, I dont want the .html appended, I want the URL to simply say /signup as opposed to /signup.html

Comment: Also, just noticed that this seems to negatively effect other files by attempting to add .html onto the end of the URL's being requested. (such as images or other resources!)

Comment: If you want only have one rewrite do not set RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(htm|html)$ and do only RewriteRule /signup$ /signup.html [QSA,R=307]